# Laptop wireless card help? BCM4311

Tags: wireless, networking

Okay I have an Acer Aspire 5517, it have bcm 4311 802 wireless card,Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Here is the output of `sudo lshw`

```
  *-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
  vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
  logical name: eth0
  version: c0
  serial: 00:26:22:15:75:4d
  size: 100Mbit/s
  capacity: 100Mbit/s
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
  resources: irq:43 memory:d1000000-d103ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

I tried this [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx) didn't work. 
For chili55 I did this

```
    laptop@laptop-Aspire-5517:~$ lspci
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
    00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
    00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
    00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
    00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
    00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
    00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
    00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
    00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
    00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
    00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
    00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
    01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
    02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
    08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)

    $sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: We don't see your Broadcom card above. Please run: lspci -nn -d 14e4: and edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Is the pci.id 14e4:4315?

Comment: Any other info you need? @chili555

Comment: Yes, please. In addition to confirming the pci.id as I requested, please confirm your Ubuntu version: lsb_release -d

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS installed

Comment: It is 14e4:4315, that up above is what popped up when I did 'sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source' @chili555

Comment: That is usually because either Software Manager, Updater or Synaptic is open. Please close and try again.

Comment: Rebooted 2 more times and it Worked Thank you now I don't have to sit on the ground with this laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, although you have been unable to confirm it, that this command:

```
lspci -nn
```

...shows your wireless device as 14e4:4315. If that is not true, please post the result. If it is true, please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it is not installed, that's fine, just proceed with the next steps:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working as expected.